# Error while running spark job because of the native files missing

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, spark-submit, snappy

I was getting this error `java.lang.RuntimeException: native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support.` while running a spark submit job.

What I did was copied `libhadoop.so` and `libsnappy.so` inside `java/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.212.b04-0.e11_10.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/` Then the process has been running without any issues. Found solution [here](https://discuss.itversity.com/t/sparkshell-native-snappy-library-not-available-error-cloudera-5-8-vm/4089) .

Before I copying I was adding  `--driver-library-path /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/lib/native/`
as part of the submit job but that didnt work, I also tried adding it to `HADOOP_OPTS`, all in vain.

Can someone explain how copying it to java amd64 folder made things work?

Answer (score 0):

The executors are what need the native libraries, not the Spark driver, which would explain why `--driver-library-path` wouldn't work.

It's unclear how/where you set `HADOOP_OPTS`, but it's probably a similar issue.

Your solution works because you now have made every Java process have access to those files, not only the Hadoop/Spark processes.

Comment: how do I specifically add it to executors, is it like  --conf spark.executor.extraLibraryPath=/user/current/hadoop/lib/native/ \

Comment: That looks correct.